# How to convert currency in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have to make conversions between currencies in my Django project. This app has multiple customers and every customer has `credit_limit` field. Every customer's credit limit amount can be in a different currency and I have to convert all of them to the USD. Because I have a dashboard page and I display some charts with doing operations with these currencies like adding etc...

I used `django-money` and works fine, but it returns `Money` field and I cannot display it in charts because it is not a float or int field.

How can I convert my currencies and return integer of float values?
Thanks for any helping.

Here are my codes:

**views.py**

```
def customer(request):
    form_class = NewCustomerForm
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    company = userP[0].company
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newCustomer = form.save()
            newCustomer.company = company
            selected_currency = newCustomer.currency_choice
            selected_limit = newCustomer.credit_limit
            newCustomer.usd_credit_limit = convert_money(Money(selected_limit, selected_currency), 'USD')
            newCustomer.save()
            return redirect('user:customer_list')
    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request, 'customer.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
...

    CURRENCIES = [
        ('USD', 'USD'),
        ('EUR', 'EUR'),
        ('GBP', 'GBP'),
    ]
    currency_choice = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='Select', choices=CURRENCIES)
    credit_limit = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    usd_credit_limit = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', null=True, default=0)
    risk_rating = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Select', choices=RISK_RATING, null=True)
```

Comment: you tried direct type conversion ?

Comment: How can I do that? I tried float(newCustomer.usd_credit_limit) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this works or if this is efficient. but try this ......

Strings with decimals cannot be immediately cast to an integer because integers do not have decimals, but floats do handle decimals and can be cast to integers. so it is easy to get float.

```
cred_limit = newCustomer.usd_credit_limit
value = str(cred_limit)[1:]

float_str = float(value) // this is your float value
print(float_str)
```

ps . if you want integer , then Call float(string) to convert string into a float. Call int(float_obj) with float_obj as the result of the previous step to convert float_obj into an integer.

Comment: there is an error when I applied: IndexError at /customer
list index out of range

Comment: try this and tell me the output :::::::  value = str(newCustomer.usd_credit_limit).split() print(value)

Comment: ['$27.36'] This is the output